# AndroidRuntime error: Parcel: unable to marshal value

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass a HashMap to a new activity using the intent.puExtra function.  Stepping through the debugger it seems that it adds the HashMap no problem, however when startActivty() is called I get a runtime error stating that Parcel: unable to marshal value com.appName.Liquor.

Liquor is a custom class that I created, and I believe it, in combination with a HashMap, is causing the problem.  If I pass a string rather than my HashMap it loads the next activity no problem.

Main Activity

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {

      String cat = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
      Intent i = new Intent(OhioLiquor.this, Category.class);
      i.putExtra("com.appName.cat", _liquorBase.GetMap());
      startActivity(i);
```

Liquor Class

```
public class Liquor
{
public String name;
public int code;
public String category;

private HashMap<String, Bottle> _bottles;

public Liquor()
{
    _bottles = new HashMap<String, Bottle>();
}

public void AddBottle(Bottle aBottle)
{
    _bottles.put(aBottle.size, aBottle);
}
}
```

Sub Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    HashMap<Integer, Liquor> map = (HashMap<Integer, Liquor>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("com.appName.cat");

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, GetNames(map)));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

When the runtime error exists it never makes it into the sub activity class.  So I'm pretty sure the problem exists in the adding of the HashMap to the intent, and based off the error I believe my Liquor class is the cause, but I can't figure out why.

Your help will be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Your `HashMap` itself is serializable but is the `Bottle` class serializable? If not, it will not serialize and will throw errors at runtime.
Make the `Bottle` class implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface

Comment: Thanks, I had to add implements Serializable to both the Liquor and Bottle classes.

Comment: it works..  I have to implement Serializable in Bottle class.  Thanks @naikus

Comment: Liquor is always to blame :))

Comment: It works, but I am confused what does Serialization has to do with this? Does Android keep on periodically serializing and deserializing objects? And in what cases do I need to implement the Serializable interface (like here)?

Comment: Work for me, with kotlin, after implement  `data class products(val name: String) : Serializable`

Comment: Liquor should not be blamed in any  case

Comment: @RafaelGuimarães incredible! Thank you. These days I often work on Kotlin and have to translate each resolution from Java to kotlin became hectic.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this error because my class wasnt `Serializable`. To make my class serializable I had to add `: Serializable` at the end of class to make is Serializable. Just like this

```
class Shirt(val price: Double, val discountedPrice: Double) : Serializable
```

Make sure to import `Serializable` like this

```
import java.io.Serializable
```