# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Tags: android, serialization, arraylist, ioexception

i have to pass Arraylist to another activity. i put my code below.

**ResultList.java**

```
import org.json.JSONArray;  
import org.json.JSONObject;        
import java.io.Serializable;   
import java.util.ArrayList;  

public class ResultList implements Serializable   
{            
    private ArrayList<JSONObject> parliaments;

    public ResultList(ArrayList<JSONObject> data) {
        this.parliaments = data;
    }

    public ArrayList<JSONObject> getParliaments() {
        return this.parliaments;
    }
}
```

**In My First Activity**

```
listData = new ResultList(resultList);// resultList is ArrayList<JSONObject>

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MainViewActivity.this, ResultShowActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("resultData", listData);
this.startActivity(resultIntent);
```

Can Anyone Help me?

what i am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204324/java-lang-runtimeexception-parcelable-encountered-ioexception-writing-serializa

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918220/jsonobject-not-serializable

Answer (score 1):

I Solved My Problem. I used ArrayList < String> instead of ArrayList< JSONObject>

that's work fine.