# Not able to intent from Fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have added fragment from code and passed data from activity to fragment when they are created ,now when i write the code to intent away from that fragments to some other activity Im getting the...java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value

This is the code I'm using in my Main class to create Fragments

```
Log.e("list=",data.toString());
fragments.add(MyFragment.newInstance(data,values.toString(),response1));
data=new ArrayList<>();
pageAdapter=new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
```

This is the actual Fragment class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment   {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE1 = "Check";
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE2 = "Check1";
    String order_id;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    SwipeMenuListView listView;

    public static final MyFragment newInstance(List<Data> data,String check,String response)
    {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(3);
        bdl.putSerializable(EXTRA_MESSAGE, (Serializable) data);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE1, check);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE2, response);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        List<Data> message = (List<Data>) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        final String show = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE1);
        final String responseaa=getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE2);
    }
}
```

Now in OnCreateView ,when Im using intent to move to another activity it is giving java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value

This is the log

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
>   com.sindhibandhan.digitalstrikers.dynamicfragement.Data@30898801
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1337)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:711)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1284)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
>                                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:142)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1191)
>                                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:396)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1357)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1262)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
>                                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2992)
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3450)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
>                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
>                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)

Comment: Show me your code, please

Comment: @ArthurKorchagin..Please look at the code now

Comment: Show logcat error message too with stack trace

Comment: @VygintasB It is shown Now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Data object is not serializable.

```
public class Data implements Serializable{

}
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819146/5512020).

Comment: You are asking about the main class ,in this case ?

Comment: You have created an object class having the name Data...do this over there

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been fighting with this all day, tested with Parcelables and nothing, but this answers works great, I thought that was the serializable because of the use of the annotations but clearly I was wrong, thanks.