# RunTimeException: unble to marshal value

Tags: android, runtime-error

I am using **Retrofit** to load images into a `RecyclerView`, ten at a time. When the user scrolls the `RecyclerView` to the bottom position, ten more images get loaded.  When the `Activity` goes into the pause-state (`onPause`) I get a **`RunTimeException`**.

This is not a duplicate question. I have checked online and have come across similar questions, but the cause of such exception was different... Please look below:

**Exception:**

```
Process: com.globemaster.samples, PID: 13132<br/>
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value** 
    com.globemaster.samples.RetroPhoto@150122e at 
    android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1418) at 
    android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:759) at 
    android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1365) at 
    android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:686) at 
    android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330) at 
    android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079) at 
    android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:711) at 
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:157) at 
    android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1254) at 
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:617) at      android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1437) at 
    android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1343) at 
    android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:686) at 
    android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330) at 
    android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079) at 
    android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:711)at 
    android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3752) at    android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4700) at 
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at 
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at 
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) at 
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at 
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                GetDataService service=RetrofitClientInstance.getClient().create(GetDataService.class);
                Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call=service.getAllPhotos();
                call.enqueue(new Callback<List<RetroPhoto>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call, Response<List<RetroPhoto>> response) {

                        Log.e("OnResponse","Called");
                        data=response.body();
                        arrayList= (ArrayList) data;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                Recycler_Frag recycler_frag=new Recycler_Frag();
                                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();                             
                                bundle.putStringArrayList("list",arrayList);
                                recycler_frag.setArguments(bundle);
                                transaction.replace(R.id.frame,recycler_frag).commit();

                            }
                        });
                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<RetroPhoto>> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("OnFailure","Called");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**Recycler_Frag.java**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_lyt,container,false);

     arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
     importedlist=new ArrayList();

     arrayList2=new ArrayList<String>();

     importedlist=getArguments().getStringArrayList("list");
     if (importedlist.size()>0){

     for(counter=0;counter<10;counter++)
     {
         retroPhoto= (RetroPhoto) importedlist.get(counter);
         arrayList.add(retroPhoto.getThumbnailUrl());
     }
         standardsize=counter;
         previouslength= arrayList.size();

     }
     progressBar=view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
     relativeLayout=view.findViewById(R.id.relative);
     recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
     recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(getContext(),arrayList));
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
     recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
         @Override
         public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
             super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
         }
         @Override
         public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
             super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
             try {
                 if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1))
                 {

                     if (!isScrolledup){


                         isScrolledup=true;
                         new Thread(new Runnable() {
                             @Override
                             public void run()
                             {
                                 relativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void run() {
                                         relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                     }
                                 });
                                 while (counter<standardsize+11)
                                 {

                                     retroPhoto= (RetroPhoto) importedlist.get(counter);
                                     arrayList2.add(retroPhoto.getThumbnailUrl());
                                     counter++;
                                 }

                                 standardsize=counter;
//

                                 recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void run() {

                                         Iterator iterator=arrayList2.iterator();
                                         while(iterator.hasNext())
                                         {
                                             arrayList.add(iterator.next());
                                         }
                                         arrayList2.clear();
                                         recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(previouslength,arrayList.size()-previouslength);



//                                         recyclerView.scrollToPosition(arrayList.size()-1);
                                     }
                                 });

                         relativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                                 relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                             }
                         });

                             }
                         }).start();

                         Toast.makeText(getContext(),"last",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

         }
     });
        return view;
    }
    public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder>{

        private ArrayList<RetroPhoto> dataList;
        private Context context;
        private RecyclerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<RetroPhoto> dataList)
        {
            this.context=context;
            this.dataList=dataList;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            return new RecyclerHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,
                    parent,false));
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerHolder holder, int position) {

//            dataList.get(position).getThumbnailUrl()
            Picasso.with(context).load(String.valueOf(dataList.get(position)))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).into(holder.imageView);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return arrayList.size();
        }

        public class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView textView;ImageView imageView;
            public RecyclerHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("OnPause","Called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("OnResume","Called");
    }
}
```

**RetroPhoto.java:**

```
public class RetroPhoto {
    @SerializedName("albumId")
    private Integer albumId;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("url")
    private String url;

    @SerializedName("thumbnailUrl")
    private String thumbnailUrl;


    public RetroPhoto(Integer albumId,Integer id,String title,String url,String thumbnailUrl)
    {
     this.albumId=albumId;
     this.id=id;
     this.title=title;
     this.url=url;
     this.thumbnailUrl=thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public Integer getAlbumId() {
        return albumId;
    }

    public void setAlbumId(Integer albumId) {
        this.albumId = albumId;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public class RetroPhoto implements Parcelable`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AndroidRuntime error: Parcel: unable to marshal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818745/androidruntime-error-parcel-unable-to-marshal-value)

Comment: Why should I implement it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818745/androidruntime-error-parcel-unable-to-marshal-value

Comment: The title is vague, you should maybe make it more specific.