# Pass HashMap<Integer, JSONObject> via intent as extra

Tags: android, android-activity

I tried to pass an HashMap via intent from fragment to activity, but without success.
this is my code:

```
    private HashMap<Integer, JSONObject> myData;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(),MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("myMap", myData);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and I got a runtimeExeption:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
```

I would be happy if someone can help me with that!
I need a way to resolve it, I know that JSONObject is not Serializable. 
The value is not a custom object, therfore I can't implement Serializable there.
Thank a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AndroidRuntime error: Parcel: unable to marshal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818745/androidruntime-error-parcel-unable-to-marshal-value)

Comment: this is from stacktrace  - `java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
HashMap<Integer, JSONObject> myData
```

you should use

```
HashMap<Integer, String> myData
```

And add the items as Strings instead of JSONObject:

```
myData.put(0, myJsonObject.toString());
```

then, on your second activity, you create the JSON when needed:

```
new JSONObject(myData.get(0));
```

The reason:

[JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) is not serializable by default but [String](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String) is (notice it implements  Serializable).