# Pass PublicKey Object from service to activity in Android?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, public-key, aidl

I'm trying to pass a `PublicKey` object from a service to an activity. However, the `Aidl` doesn't seem to support the `PublicKey` type. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your public key you should put it into the /res/raw/ folder and retrieve it from there. Or store it in filesystem `activity.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()` would be your path. You can also use  - pass Objects over IPC as described here in the article http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html 
hope this helps.

Comment: @Benner Thank you very much for you answer . in fact , I should have mentioned that the service and the activity does not belong to the same application , so I guess that your first suggestion does not apply in this case . I checked your link to the android developpers forum. I think i have to use the parcel and parcelable . But since i'm a newbie in android , i still don't get how to use them correctly , especially with the java  PublicKey object . Thanks again.

Comment: you can save the Object into a byte array and set it to parcel then get it from there. Here're some posts about parcels and byte arrays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058003/beautiful-way-to-read-file-into-byte-array-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626667/how-to-use-parcel-in-android