# Android Parcel how to write Bundle

Tags: java, android

I want to write a Bundle into a Parcel, I use the Parcel.writeBundle Method. 
I can write it without any Problem but if I want to read it with Parcel.readBundle it returns an empty bundle. What am i doing wrong?
Here is my Code:

```
 Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
 p.writeParcelable(device, 0);
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
 b.putString("serial_number",MainActivity.this.T_Serialnbr);
 b.putString("model_number", null);
 b.putString("mac_address", device.getAddress());
 p.writeBundle(b);
 Bundle b1 =  p.readBundle(); // empty Bundle
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626667/how-to-use-parcel-in-android
see this link